# Fontcustom Less template to generate custom icon fonts

Tags: fonts, icons, less

Im looking for a fontcustom template to generate less, rather than scss. Are there any out there?

http://fontcustom.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS template (By default, Font Custom will generate css and preview files for you.) and import that into your Less project.

Save the CSS templates as yourfont.css and than in your Less code:

```
@import (css) "yourfont.css";
```

See also: http://lesscss.org/features/#import-directives-feature